# HandlebarsTemplates is not defined

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, handlebars.js

After following the instructions on [handlebars_assets](https://github.com/leshill/handlebars_assets#javascript-setup),

i still can't get it to work.

My steps were:

1) Added gem 'handlebars_assets' on Gemfile

2) run bundle install

3) Made sure application.js has //= require vendor/handlebars-v2.0.0

4) Added //= require_tree ./handlebars_templates to the application.js too

5) handlebars_templates directory is under app/assets/javascripts

6) Added test.hbs to the handlebars_templates directory

7) test.hbs contains `<div>test hbs</div>`

8) In a backbone.js view I've written

```
template: HandlebarsTemplates['handlebars_template/new_map/infoWindow'](context),
```

The error I received when loading the browser was:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: HandlebarsTemplates is not defined
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: Are you sure the scripts are loading in the correct order?  i.e. handlebars is actually loaded when you call it?

Comment: @BanksySan Yes i'm sure

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you restart your rails server after installing the `handlebars_assets` gem!